# Understanding shape of DSN's 'kinky uplink protocol' keeping frequency in coherent transponder's optimum bandpass?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, radio-communication, deep-space-network, doppler-ranging, delay-doppler

This [tweet](https://twitter.com/df2mz/status/1081321091342192641) by deep space SDR enthusiast and amateur radio operator Edgar Kaiser @df2mz shows a squiggly tone from MRO.

> Mars Reconnaiscance Orbiter (MRO) X-band downlink. The signal shows this kinky behavior due to a specific uplink protocol keeping the uplink signal frequency within the optimum bandpass of the spacecraft's coherent transponder. Distance was 193 million km.

**Question:** I would like to **understand the details of shape** of this frequency versus time plot of received signals from MRO.

It runs about 13 minutes long and shows a general quadratic behavior with some superimposed stepping. Is there a name for this, or documentation? How does this relate specifically to MRO's orbit?

CLICK for full size:

[image]

Comment: The overall slight increase of frequency is just Doppler effect as both sender and receiver are accelerating. The wiggly structure can't be seen in any of the recordings that uhf-satcom did: https://twitter.com/search?q=%40uhf_satcom%20mro&src=typd Maybe a slight hint of them in some.

Comment: @asdfex I'm particularly interested in "understand(ing) the details of shape" of this "just a doppler effect" as well as the wiggles.